# PHP str_replace with the contents of a file

Tags: php

I'm wanting to create something like short codes like WordPress uses. So when a user puts *[related]* into a post, it will show the content inside *include "includes/related_article_inline.php"* instead of *[related]*. What I've tried so far is:

```
$searchString = '[related]';
$replacementString = '<?php echo include "includes/related_article_inline.php"; ?>';
echo str_replace( $searchString ,$replacementString ,$post_content );
```

but, this isn't quite working properly. Anybody know how I can replace *[related]* with the contents of *includes/related_article_inline.php*?

Comment: What are you expecting? the contents of `related_article_inline.php` as the replacement or the string `include "includes/related_article_inline.php";` as the replacement?

Comment: I'm wanting to sort of make like shortcode things like Wordpress uses. So when a user put *[related]* it will show the content inside *include "includes/related_article_inline.php"* instead of *[related]*. There is probably a better way to do this, but I haven't found the answer. **EDIT** Sorry it's suppose to be "<?php include "includes/related_article_inline.php";?>

Comment: I accidentally put the wrong thing. I edited the original post above to what it's supposed to say.

Comment: Depending on the construction of `includes/related_article_inline.php`, you may need to make use of [output buffereing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). Otherwise it is possible to assign the return value from an included file to a variable like `$replacementString = include('includes/related_article_inline.php');`. I absolutly want to say don't use `eval()` for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. The .php file includes php and html and whatnot. It works if I just put it in simply as **<?php echo include "includes/related_article_inline.php"; ?>** but trying to echo it doesn't work.

Comment: I've moved some of the discussion from the comments into the question body so future readers don't have to read through those to figure out what the desired result is. I've also altered the title to add a little more context to what the question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_replace` doesn't include the file, but it will just do a simple string-replacement. So your browser will show

> include "includes/related_article_inline.php";

somewhere, at the position you added the `[replace]`.

Two possible solutions.

1) If you know on forehand the `[replace]` will be in your post-content: include it before your `str_replace`, store the output into a string (using [output-buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)), and do the actual replacement.

```
ob_start(); // Start output buffering
include "includes/related_article_inline.php";
$replacementString = ob_get_clean(); // Store output in variable, and stop output-buffering
echo str_replace($searchString, $replacementString, $post_content);
```

2) If you don't know on forehand `[replace]` will be in your post-content, you probably don't always want to include it. Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) so the file will then only be included if necessary.

```
$replacementFunction = function() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    include "includes/related_article_inline.php";
    return ob_get_clean(); // Return output, and stop output-buffering
};
$searchRegex = '/\[replace\]/'; // You have to rewrite your search-string to a regular expression
echo preg_replace_callback($searchRegex, $replacementFunction, $post_content);
```

Comment: Oh hey! Solution #1 worked great! Thank you so much!